# How to get row count until specific AI ID?

Tags: mysql

I've been working on a bot in Discord. I came across a problem that causes lag in the system itself. I am trying to count until a specific ID is found, but I only need the count (which is the local ID of the user).

This led to trying to find comparable issues on Stackoverflow and other websites. The closest I've come to solving this problem is what causes lag. So my question is, is there a more efficient query I can use for this problem?

The current query that I'm trying to work with is:

```
SELECT
    global_id,
    COUNT(*) AS `Count`
FROM claim AS cl
WHERE
    cl.fk_user_id = '<user_id>'
    AND cl.global_id = (
        SELECT cl.global_id
        FROM `claim` AS cl2
        WHERE cl.global_id <= <global_id_to_be_compared_with>
        ORDER BY cl2.global_id DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )
GROUP BY cl.global_id
ORDER BY cl.global_id
```

This however returns multiple rows with `global_id` and `Count`, but count always being 1.

```
global_id | Count
1           1
2           1
3           1
4           1
5           1
6           1
```

However what I expect it to be would be:

```
global_id | Count
6           6
```

It shouldn't display global_id 7 for example, which would be count 7.

My solution works for what I want it to do, but it does cause lag in the bot itself, which I would rather reduce then let it stick around.

Edit:
Found an even faster way to execute the query thanks to @scaisEdge

```
SELECT
    COUNT(distinct global_id)
FROM claim AS cl
WHERE cl.fkc_user_id = '<user_id>'
    AND cl.global_id <= <global_id_to_be_compared_with>
ORDER BY cl.global_id
```

Comment: Please share the data sample on which you're executing given query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using count distinct

```
    SELECT
        count(distinct global_id),
        COUNT(*) AS `Count`
    FROM claim AS cl
    WHERE
        cl.fk_user_id = '<user_id>'
        AND cl.global_id = (
            SELECT cl.global_id
            FROM `claim` AS cl2
            WHERE cl.global_id <= <global_id_to_be_compared_with>
            ORDER BY cl2.global_id DESC
            LIMIT 1
        )
```